# Difference between HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad vs HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad in HBASE

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

Can you please tell me what is the difference between `HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad vs HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad` in HBASE as both approach is working fine? Is there any performance improvement?

Answer (score 1):

If you use version of HBase where these two classes coexist (0.96+) then there is absolutely no difference between them.

You can check the code for [HFileOutputFormat](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/branch-1.3/hbase-server/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/HFileOutputFormat.java) and see that `HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad` just calls the same method from `HFileOutputFormat2`:

```
public static void configureIncrementalLoad(Job job, HTable table)
  throws IOException {
HFileOutputFormat2.configureIncrementalLoad(job, table.getTableDescriptor(),
    table.getRegionLocator());
}
```

This behaviour is present in all version of HBase since 0.96 where HFileOutputFormat2 was added.